# PolyUtil.containsLocation() returns wrong value

Tags: java, android, geometry, location, polygon

I have a list of polygons that I read from **kml** file

```
List<LatLng> polygon = new ArrayList<>();
for (Point p:placemark.getPoint()) {
    l = new LatLng(p.getLatitude(),p.getLongitude());
    polygon.add(l);    
}
```

Those are the points in **KML**

```
<coordinates>
          46.7614175,24.7143556,0
          46.7639557,24.7113615,0
          46.7659298,24.7083206,0
          46.7676464,24.7058254,0
          46.7707363,24.7014588,0
          46.7727962,24.6959223,0
          46.7747703,24.6911654,0
          46.7764869,24.6850046,0
          46.7770019,24.6792334,0
          46.7933098,24.6842247,0
          46.8056694,24.6906195,0
          46.8183723,24.6960783,0
          46.8327919,24.7034082,0
          46.8470707,24.7123565,0
          46.8565979,24.7183601,0
          46.8627777,24.7215567,0
          46.8653526,24.7281055,0
          46.8637218,24.732783,0
          46.8588734,24.7393914,0
          46.8556977,24.7438347,0
          46.8513203,24.7493691,0
          46.8483162,24.7539678,0
          46.8450547,24.7595797,0
          46.8417931,24.7651913,0
          46.8381024,24.7619179,0
          46.8267727,24.7549811,0
          46.8082811,24.7435125,0
          46.791115,24.732443,0
          46.779957,24.7258944,0
          46.7614175,24.7143556,0
</coordinates>
```

After that I'm checking user location if it's inside this polygons or not like this:

```
if (PolyUtil.containsLocation(userLatLng,polygon,false)){
}
```

But it returns false even it's inside Like this

[image]

I'm sure `userLatLng != null` and **polygon not empty**

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the latitude and longitude swapped anywhere? That would mean the point would be somewhere near Brasov, Romania. If this does not help, would you mind providing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @DominikMokriš 
I'm sure every thing is correct
I got LatLng from map

Comment: @YahyaAlborene did you find the solution? i am facing same issue.